# Strange traffic in java sockets

Tags: java, windows, sockets, jvm, network-traffic

I'am investigating strange problem. I'am using java Sockets for IPC. And i'am worrying about strange traffic. When i use c# and transfer strings via StreamWriter it is ok:

[image]

But when i use java and ObjectOutputStream\ObjectInputStream it is very strange:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7bWSt.png]

First column is inbound traffic and second is outbound.

It is simple code:

```
ObjectOutputStream oos = ObjectOutputStream(clientScoket.getOutputStream())
oos.writeObject(someCustomObject);
```

on another side:

```
ObjectInputStream ois = ObjectInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
SomeCustomObject sco = oos.readObject();
```

How inbound traffic can be unequal to outbound? Anyone?

Comment: It's really not clear what you're showing here - we can't even see the column headers, let alone the code you're using.

Comment: @Jon, what he is asking is that why are the number of bytes sent by sender different from number of bytes recived from reciver, when using java, but when he is using C#, its same

Comment: Can you try sending just one byte and see what happens? Also if you are familiar with some sniffing tool like Wireshark to see what is being transfered while you debug step by step.

Answer (score 2):

It's some sort of problem in sniffing loopback traffic under Windows. I tried and no tools found anything (Wireshark and WinPCap cannot loopback). When you use simple streams and just write some bytes it is okay. The problem appears only with `ObjectIputStream`.